# jodd mail EmailFilter does not work

Tags: email, jodd

I use

```
receiveEmailAndMarkSeen(EmailFilter.filter().flag(Flags.Flag.SEEN,true));
```

to filter the message which I don't read, but the function returns empty array. If I set `false` it returns all the message.

I test many times, I don't know what's wrong

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend on the target server. Are you using IMAP or POP server? IMAP is the one that usually works better with your use case.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
    ImapServer imapServer = MailServer.create()
        .host("imap.gmail.com")
        .ssl(true)
        .auth("user", "password")
        .buildImapMailServer();

    ReceiveMailSession session = imapServer.createSession();
    session.open();

    ReceivedEmail[] mails =
            session.receiveEmailAndMarkSeen(
            EmailFilter.filter().flag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, false));

    Arrays.stream(mails).map(CommonEmail::subject).forEach(System.out::println);

    session.close();
```

My mailbox:

[image]

Program output:

[image]

p.s. try to download all emails and check the `Flag` of received emails. Also, use IMAP.

Comment: I used pop3.  I think you are right. thank you very much.